# alter external table in sql azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, alter-table

I am trying to alter external table column name to new name

I followed [this](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4320/ref_guide/sql_commands/ALTER_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html) post

```sql
ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE RemoteCustomerTable RENAME [OldName] column TO [Name]
```

**Error:**

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.

Can external table be altered ?

Any help would be great.

**Update:**

As i dont see any official docs to alter external table, so i droped the external table and re-created it using [this](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2016/03/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database/) post

```sql
DROP EXTERNAL TABLE RemoteCustomerTable;
```

Comment: So did you answer your own question? If so, you should post a proper answer (or delete the question).

Comment: @David Makogon, i can post it as answer but i want to know Can external table be altered in sql azure ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alter external table is not a supported operation in Azure SQL Database. As you pointed out, [DROP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt130698.aspx) and then [CREATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935021.aspx) is the way to go.